# How to change caption of nodes from nodetype to fully specified name property?

Tags: neo4j, knowledge-graph

I am working with Snomed in Neo4j bloom.
I used the steps from the tutorial https://medium.com/@john.newberry27/populating-a-snomed-ct-property-graph-with-synthetic-patient-data-a43a3a044649 to create the graph database. However, there is a step in the tutorial to change what property nodes use as caption in neo4j bloom that is represented in the following image:
[image]

However, following the same steps and going into the same location, I find only the option to exclude:[image]

I am using the neo4j 2.10.1 version. Anybody has any ideas about why this is the case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[As documented](https://neo4j.com/docs/bloom-user-guide/current/bloom-visual-tour/legend-panel/#_default_styling), you now set the properties to display in Bloom in the `Legend Panel`'s `Text` tab.

[image]